# Rails 3 + Devise + Rspec - undefined method error in Controller test

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, devise, factory-bot

I have such **spec** (spec/controllers/stats_controller_spec.rb) to test my controller:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe StatsController do
  render_views

  before(:each){ @user = FactoryGirl.create( :user ) }

  describe "GET 'users_in_system'" do
    describe "for non-signed users" do
      it "should deny access" do
        get :users_in_system, :locale => :en
        #...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When i run this spec i get such **error**:

```
1) StatsController GET 'users_in_system' for non-signed users should deny access
     Failure/Error: get :users_in_system, :locale => :en
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/layouts/_navbar_template.html.haml:16:in `_app_views_layouts__navbar_template_html_haml__2938837959272005060_70149962955560'
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml__243298846079092947_70149956982200'
     # ./spec/controllers/stats_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I tried to solve this error by adding this line to (spec/spec_helper.rb):

```
#...

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  #...
end
```

Then i started to get such error:

```
1) StatsController GET 'users_in_system' for non-signed users should deny access
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/devise-2.1.0/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:33:in `warden'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-rails-2.10.0/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in setup'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:178:in `instance_eval'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:178:in `instance_eval'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:23:in `run'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:63:in `block in run'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:63:in `each'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:63:in `run'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:400:in `run_hook'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:298:in `run_before_each_hooks'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:239:in `run_before_each'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:86:in `block in run'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:195:in `with_around_each_hooks'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:84:in `run'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:353:in `block in run_examples'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:349:in `map'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:349:in `run_examples'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:335:in `run'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:336:in `block in run'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:336:in `map'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:336:in `run'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:336:in `block in run'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:336:in `map'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:336:in `run'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block in run'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:34:in `report'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
     # /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

I tried to add that (spec/controllers/stats_controller_spec.rb):

```
describe StatsController do
  render_views
  include Devise::TestHelpers
  #...
end
```

But that changed nothing. How can i repair that?

**UPD**:
My stats controller:

```
class StatsController < ApplicationController
  def users_in_system
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

My navbar:

```
%div{ :class => "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" }
  %div{ :class => "navbar-inner" }
    %a{:class => "btn btn-navbar", "data-toggle" => "collapse", "data-target" => ".nav-collapse"}
      %span{:class=>"icon-bar"}
      %span{:class=>"icon-bar"}
      %span{:class=>"icon-bar"}

    = link_to t(".brand_name"), root_path, { :class => "brand" }
    %div{ :class => "nav-collapse" }
      -# Left navigation.
      %ul{ :class => "nav" }
        %li=link_to "About", about_path

      -# Right navigation.
      %ul{ :class => "nav pull-right" }
        - if user_signed_in?
          %li=link_to t(".settings"), edit_user_registration_path
          %li{ :class => "divider-vertical" }
          %li=link_to t(".logout_link"), destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete
```

Comment: can you add `app/views/layouts/_navbar_template.html.haml`, several lines around line 16 if it's big; and some code from `StatsController`: `users_in_system` action and before/around filters if any?

Comment: @SergeBalyuk I added navbar and controller.

Comment: What happens if you *don't* `render_views`?

Comment: @RyanBigg I tried that. Error is same: `Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace NoMethodError: undefined method env for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your backtrace looks like you're using `rspec-rails` `2.10.0` which had [this issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/534) with setup callbacks order. Try upgrading version of that specific gem to `2.10.1` as it should have it fixed.

You're on the right path with

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  #...
end
```

so I think you can remove explicit `include Devise::TestHelpers` from your spec file.